# DynamoDB sorted pull

Tags: amazon-web-services, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

So I'm working with DynamoDB. My primary key is some unique identifier and then one of the other columns is a timestamp columns. I'd like to pull just the first N events and then continue to pull later events if the client requests this.

I don't know if this is possible to do in Dynamo. Is it possible? How would I go about it? I can redesign the table if needed.

Right now, it seems like the only way to do this would be to run a query all the data in the table and then sort the results returned.

Comment: How much data are you planning to store? How many events would there typically be that you’d be querying against? Can you give some concrete examples?  DynamoDB is not a timeseries database but you can certainly implement what you are asking for in certain cases.

Comment: @MikeDinescu It could become quite large. I think what will work is creating a secondary index that'll partition by username and then have a secondary index as timestamp. That way, I can pull information from a specified time interval and if more data is requested, I can pull the additional observations. Does that sound like a good solution?

Comment: Depending on how much data you have per user, yes it may be a good solution